# Sublime Text 2 input laggy

Tags: performance

I use Sublime Text 2 (ST2) both on Linux & OS X Lion. When entering text, interacting with menus etc, ST2 is very laggy - I can type a few sentences very quickly, then take my hands of the keyboard and watch ST2 catch up.

I've tried reverting ST2 by deleting the `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2` folder, but the issue persists.

Does anyone know what can cause this lagginess?

**Update**: Activity Monitor shows ST2 idles at around 5-16% CPU. When typing, it spikes to 80-100%.

Comment: What do you mean with "entering text, interactive with menus"? You probably first should look at running processes to see what makes your computer lag behind. You can use Activity Monitor for that.

Comment: Do you have any extra packages installed? If so, which ones?

Comment: I've tried it with none, I get the same behaviour

Comment: If ST2 is the only application where you're seeing this issue, I would report this in [Sublime Text's support forum](http://www.sublimetext.com/support).

Answer (score 1):

This issue seems to have been solved in the latest development build:

http://www.sublimetext.com/dev